# Multistep forms using CodeIgniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter, jquery, multi-step

I am trying to build a multistep form with CodeIgniter,but I cant figure it out how it should be.My thoughts are to create for each step different contoller functions and views. Is my thought right or is there any better way to implement it?
Do you recommend to create the fomrs using AJAX?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For youe problem i can suggest two solutions.
It is up to you either you use ajax or form post.

Method 1

1.One first setp save the data to table
2.In the second and all other steps update the table.
If you are going to give back functionality you will 
have to work carefully and make sure your form code has 
primary key when at least step one has passed through.

Method 2
In this method do not save in the table just through 
each form post to session and when the final step is 
passed through you can save the data to table from session
once and for all

Comment: Thank you for replying I was thinking also the second method, because 
I want to save to the database at the last form. 
But my questions still remains, do I have to create different controller fucntions and views for each step of the form?

Comment: yes sure you can create a single controller and multiple methods and multiple views will be required